# Cron jobs for deactivated plugins

Tags: cron

Hi I am using a plugin to view the cron jobs that are run by wordpress. I am noticing that there are jobs related to plugins I have deactivated and even deleted. Why is this so and how can I remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because the plugins you were using didnt deregister the crons it setup. To remove the crons use the following code in your functions file:

```
add_action("init", "clear_crons_left");
function clear_crons_left() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook("cron_name");
}
```

Once thats run once you can safely remove it

Comment: Tried this out but it crashed my wp, removed it now and the crons are still there.

Comment: You have accepted this answer? I presume you figured out the issue you were having?

Comment: no sorry I still cannot get it to work. I replaced

Comment: No sorry I replaced 'cron_name' with the name of the cron job but when I save the functions file and refresh the page WP crashes. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: oops sorry missed a `;` off the end of the line. try the code again.

Comment: I just have one cron left which I cannot remove, 
ithemes-backupbuddy-cron_schedule
It has an argument [0]: 1

Comment: `wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_new_event', array('some_arg'));`

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing jobs that are related to plugins that were deactivated because its a badly coded plugin which should have cleared the scheduled job when it was deactivated,

any way you can uncshedule them using   [**`wp_unschedule_event`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unschedule_event).